# Finding A Convolution

Tags: convolution

Let $f(x)=e^{- \mid x \mid},  g(x)= e^{-x^2}$

What is $(f*g)(\xi)$?

I have been trying to find it, but I am stuck on finding the integral of $e^{y^2+y+\xi}$

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't $f(x)=e^{-|x|},\ g(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: You're right! I'll fix that.